# How do I find what user owns a HIVE database?

Tags: hive

I want to confirm which user is the owner of a database in HIVE. Where would I find this information?

Answer (score 7):

[DESCRIBE|DESC DATABASE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Describe) shows the name of the database, its comment (if one has been set), and its root location on the filesystem. The uses of `SCHEMA` and `DATABASE` are interchangeable – they mean the same thing. `DESCRIBE SCHEMA` is added in Hive 0.15 ([HIVE-8803](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8803)).

EXTENDED also shows the database properties.

```
DESCRIBE DATABASE [EXTENDED] db_name;
DESCRIBE SCHEMA [EXTENDED] db_name;     -- (Note: Hive 0.15.0 and later)
```

These examples show that `cards` database was created by `cloudera` user:

```
hive> SET hive.cli.print.header=true;
hive> describe database cards;
OK
db_name comment location    owner_name  owner_type  parameters
cards       hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/cards.db    cloudera    USER    
Time taken: 0.013 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

---

```
hive> desc schema cards;
OK
db_name comment location    owner_name  owner_type  parameters
cards       hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/cards.db    cloudera    USER    
Time taken: 0.022 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

---

Alternatively,

Hive database is nothing but a hdfs directory in Hive warehouse dir location with `.db` extension. You can get user by simply from `hadoop fs -ls` command:

For a directory it returns list of its direct children as in Unix. A directory is listed as:

```
permissions userid groupid modification_date modification_time dirname
```

Files within a directory are order by filename by default.

Example:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/*.db |awk '{print $3,$NF}'
```

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Both will solve your problem:

```
hive> describe database extended db_name;

hive> describe schema extended db_name;
```

The output will have the owner user name.

Answer (score -1):

If you have configured the hive to an external metastore like mysql or derby , you can query the metastore table **DBS** to get the information .

**Query**

`select NAME,OWNER_NAME,OWNER_TYPE from DBS;`

**Output**

```
+--------------+------------+------------+
| NAME         | OWNER_NAME | OWNER_TYPE |
+--------------+------------+------------+
| default      | public     | ROLE       |
| employee     | addy       | USER       |
| test         | addy       | USER       |
```